# Angular velocity parameter spec from AMS datasheet range units and sensitiviy

Tags: motor, encoder, velocity

I cannot understand this specificaion and hoping someone could explain in detail.
I do not particular (atm) care for the Cut Off frequency row, but the rest I do.

First I struggle to understand their units and units per bit, and then cannot make sense of the the spec'ed sensitivity.

Starting from top,  Vres is 14 bit signed, Vrange is -28000, to +28000. That is then 56000+1(with 0) total range, so / 16384  = 3.41810 per bit.  And this seems odd, if this is RPM (implying I won't see any change in less than 3 revolutions ..? )

Sensitivity I don't understand notation either: is that degrees-second-bit, or ? How does one derive that 24.141, and if that's not derivable from given, how to use this with the reported velocity..?
[image]

Comment: It means its resolution is 3.4181 rpm. I.e. if you read a value of 1 from the device, the rpm = 3.4181. You read 10 = 34.181rpm, you read 8195 = 28011rpm.

Comment: @Kartman: well that's what I got above, and it also means, you never detect change in velocity below 3.14181 rpm, and thats  a bit odd to me.

Comment: 3 rpm is awfully slow. These devices and expected to be used on internal combustion engines, so 3 rpm is unheard of and the actual rpm varies within the cycle.  At some point the designers had to make a tradeoff between resolution and bits. What do you want the device to measure?

Comment: @Kartman: its attached to a wheel motor.  What I don't understand with this resolution of the volocity, does it mean that the wheel has to actually make the 3 rpm before velocity is reported, or it's starts getting extrapolated based on internal angle/counter values ? (It has  I think 12bit per rotation abs angle counter too)

Comment: I dare say it is the case - if you want to measure rotation less than 3rpm, then you’ll have to sample the angle and do your own calcs.

Comment: @Kartman: but what makes me convinced that my own derivation based on what they/sensor reports is going to be anymore accurate wrt velocity that it provides already / reports? I mean, naively perhaps thinking about it, but they sure know the sensor pretty well and if they only report velocity to this accuracy well ...  Is it not a safe bet that they already do 'best' estimation post a 'best' filtering ?  I'm just not experienced enough with encoders to know